# Multiple strings array of type OR in JS & Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

Here's the issue:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="question"/>

<div id="correct-answer"> 
<text>text1</text>
<text>text2</text>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#correct-answer').toggle(this.value.trim().toLowerCase() == 'text1');
});
});
```

So:

1. div #correct answer is originally hidden via CSS
2. JS shows this div on user's input matches with == 'text1'
3. Its working but I'd like in some cases use multiple correct answers
4. these multiple answers would consist of different words or alternatively of different clusters of words

**5. QUESTION:
Any idea on how to expand JS on: == 'text1' to insert multiple string arrays there?**

Im having on my mind smt like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#correct-answer').toggle(this.value.trim().toLowerCase() == 'text1' OR =='text2');
});
});
```

**In case I wanna show separate divs on separate correct answers (some questions may have multiple correct answers):**

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="question"/>

<div id="correct-answer-1"> 
<text>text1</text>
</div>

<div id="correct-answer-2"> 
<text>text2</text>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#input').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#correct-answer-1').toggle(this.value.trim().toLowerCase() == 'text1');
    $('#correct-answer-2').toggle(this.value.trim().toLowerCase() == 'text2');
});
});
```

This part of code doesn't seem to be working tho, where am I going wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use arrays to verify your answer

```
const acceptedAnswers = ['text1', 'text2'];
const answer = this.value.trim().toLowerCase();
if (acceptedAnswers.includes(answer)) {
    /* do something */
}
// or in your case
$('#correct-answer').toggle(acceptedAnswers.includes(answer));
```

Or use the OR condition, noted with `||`

```
$('#correct-answer').toggle(this.value.trim().toLowerCase() === 'text1' || this.value.trim().toLowerCase() === 'text2');
```

Comment: I have used the option with OR condition and its working pretty well thanks for your solution mate.